# how to get textbox value in jquery function..?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get for loop different  textbox value in jquery function.

MY php code :

```
<?php
        $qstid =  $addnew334->id;
        $dd = DB::table('tbltplatematerial')->where('qteid',$qstid)->get();
        foreach($dd as $d1)
        {

        $ing_id = $d1->id;
    ?> 

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $d1->name;?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtingprice" id="<?php echo $ing_id;?>" value="" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $d1->id; ?>" onClick="addpriceing(<?php echo $ing_id; ?>,<?php echo $qstid;?>,<?php echo $value;?>,<?php echo $value11;?>)" id="checkid"></td>

     <?php 
        }
    ?>
```

My jquery function:

```
    function addpriceing(ing_id,qstid,user_product_id,temp_id)
    {
            var price =  $("input[name='txtingprice']").val();
            alert(price);
            $.ajax({
            url: '<?= URL:: to('addpriceing1') ?>',
            type: 'GET',
            //dataType: "json",
            async : false,
            data:{
                    'price':price,
                    'ing_id':ing_id,
                    'qstid':qstid,
                    'user_product_id':user_product_id,
                    'temp_id':temp_id,

                  },
            success: function(e)
             {
                if(e == 0)  
                {
                    console.log("Successs");
                    alert("success");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('error');
                }
             }
        });

    }
```

I am trying to get all txtingprice value  in jquery function. Please help.

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same name. Use var price =  $("#"+ing_id).val(); instead

Comment: still I am not getting price value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating multiple textbox using foreach so instead of `name="txtingprice"` use `name="txtingprice[]"`. Also you need to loop on field name to get the value as:

```
var price = $('input[name="txtingprice[]"]').map(function(){
       return this.value
   }).get()
   alert(price);
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/28/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="reporting_person_name"></asp:TextBox >

string getValue=$('[id$=reporting_person_name]').val();
alert(getValue);
```

Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="reporting_person_name" CssClass="form-control" />

string getValue=$('[id$=reporting_person_name]').val(); alert(getValue);
alert (getValue);